# node.js pass array to mysql callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Is any possible to pass array into mysql callback like:

```
connection.query('SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = 
  \''+asid+'\'', inventory[i],function(err,wiersze){
    console.log(inventory[i]);
});
```

Now `inventory[i]` is not avaible inside, but I need to have it.

Comment: What should inventory[i] be?Which mysql module are you using? Looking at [the introduction in node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction), I'd guess you want `connection.query('SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = \''+asid+'\'', function(err,wiersze) { console.log(wiersze[0].wynik); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're inside a for-loop, you'll need to use an immediately-invoked-anonymous-function or a simple `.forEach()`. Both are provided as examples below.

**Immediately-invoked-anonymous-function**

```
for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        if (inventory[i].market_hash_name == rows[j].real_name) {
            var asid = inventory[i].assetid;
            connection.query('SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = \'' + asid + '\'', function(err, wiersze) {
                console.log(inventory[i]);
                process.exit(1);
                if (wiersze[0].wynik == 0) {
                    var employee = {
                        asset_id: asid,
                        trans_id: rows[j].tid
                    };
                    connection.query('INSERT INTO used SET ?', employee, function(err, res) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        offer.addMyItem(inventory[i]);
                    });
                    licznik++;
                }

            });

        }
    })(i);
});
```

**`.forEach()`**

```
inventory.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.market_hash_name == rows[j].real_name) {
        var asid = item.assetid;
        connection.query('SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = \'' + asid + '\'', function(err, wiersze) {
            console.log(item);
            process.exit(1);
            if (wiersze[0].wynik == 0) {
                var employee = {
                    asset_id: asid,
                    trans_id: rows[j].tid
                };
                connection.query('INSERT INTO used SET ?', employee, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    offer.addMyItem(item);
                });
                licznik++;
            }

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: if I do like this, inventory is not avaible in query block.
Return undefinited.

Comment: Could you provide a larger code sample?  There's something else going on with your code.

Comment: Ah, you are inside a for-loop. That's what I thought was happening, but no worries.  I've edited my answer with two different solutions for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have 1 more question.
How increment var licznik?
I try sth like this but it is not working.
http://pastebin.com/raw/KzeWyszf

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `callback()` directly after your string.

Try this :

```
connection.query("SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = " + asid, function(err, rows){
     /* check errors here */
     console.log(rows);
 });
```